# Manage AzureSearch via (Rest) API

Tags: rest, api, azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-management-api

I’m trying to create a tool which should scale the „Replicas“ and „Partitions“ of an Azure Search component.
For that, I read the following article from Microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/

Right now, I am having trouble authenticating against azure to get an AuthToken.
Is there a way to do it easier? Alternatively, do you guys have a sample in how to do it?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
var clientId = "2aaced54873e4a94b6d5518bc815dcb1";
var redirectUri = new Uri("https://thissucks.search.windows.net");
var resource = "resource"; // What exactly should the value be?

var authContext =
    new AuthenticationContext(
        "https://login.windows.net/ba1cb781739c4cdea71c619ccba914e0/oauth2/authorize", new TokenCache());

var result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, redirectUri, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto));
var result2 = result.Result;
```

After invoking this, I get an Azure Login screen. After login with valid credentials, I get the following Exception:

**System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred.'**

**InnerException:**

AdalServiceException: AADSTS50001: The application named  was not found in the tenant named .
This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant.
You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

Comment: What kind of tool are you trying to create? Is it a web application or a desktop application?

Comment: I want to auto scale the Azure Search component based on metrics. As of right now Azure’s auto scaling tool, only supports a handful of components … Azure Search is not one of them.

Comment: Let me ask again :) - Is the tool you're building a web application or a desktop application. You're passing some incorrect parameters and the correct value will depend on your answer.

Comment: @GauravMantri Is there a difference? If there is, my tendency is Web Application

Comment: @GauravMantri Right now it's a Console Application (to fool around), which parameters are wrong?

Comment: @DiogoFernandes Side question, are you using the Azure Search Management SDK for .NET? It's not clear from the title of your question. It's easier than using the Management REST API directly. The NuGet package is here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there're a few issues in your code.

First, please make sure that you have followed the steps described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api. Once the application is created successfully, you must note down the client id of that application and use that in your code.

Next, please ensure that `ba1cb781739c4cdea71c619ccba914e0` is indeed the tenant id. You could also use Azure AD domain name (`something.onmicrosoft.com`) instead of this GUID type value. So your URL would be `https://login.windows.net/something.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize`

Lastly, there are issues with the values for the following parameters:

```
var redirectUri = new Uri("https://thissucks.search.windows.net");
var resource = "resource"; // What exactly should the value be?
```

`redirectUri` is the URI where the `Azure AD` will redirect once the user is successfully authenticated. For `Web Applications` it is usually the URL of your website. Please make sure that it matches with the value you provided when creating an application in Azure AD. When Azure AD redirects the user to this URL, it passes a JWT token in `code` query string parameter using which you get access/refresh token.

`resource` is the resource for which you're acquiring the token. Since you want to access `Resource Manager API`, the value here should be `https://management.core.windows.net/`.

Comment: Many thanks! With this, I can hopefully try some things out.
I saw that in Azure AD (in the Register App) there is an option for “native client”. Would this also apply for the sample you wrote? Or do I need to do something entirely different?

Comment: Since you're building a console app, you would use native app. Please give it a try and update your question with any problems that you may encounter. If I have an answer to those, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I got it running and got a valid token. Thanks a lot!